# RxJS Observable item from Observable list not being updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an `observable list` of items that get's set manually through a `subject` by calling `next`.
From this list I map an `observable item` that I would expect to be updated when the `observable list` gets the data including this filtered item, but it doesn't.
Is this suppose to work like that?

```js
private devicesSubject = new ReplaySubject<Device[]>();
readonly devices$ = this.devicesSubject.asObservable();
public device$(ip: string): Observable<Device>{
  return this.devices$.pipe(map(devices => {
    return devices.find(device => device.getIp() === ip);
  }));
}

// This never gets triggered
this.device$("127.0.0.1").subscribe(device => console.log(`${device.ip}`);

// When the devices are available
devicesSubject.next(serverDevices);
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjdnlm. But of course, I had to apply fixes and changes to your code to make it run. Please do as I just did: provide a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: You are right, this is indeed working, my issue was just before this with a router param mapping. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Return the devicesSubject.asObservable() inside method instead of creating a readonly variable.

```
private devicesSubject = new ReplaySubject<Device[]>();


public device$(ip: string): Observable<Device>{
  return this.devicesSubject.pipe(map(devices => {
    return devices.find(device => device.getIp() === ip);
  }));
}
// This never gets triggered
this.device$("127.0.0.1").subscribe(device => console.log(`${device.ip}`);

// When the devices are available
devicesSubject.next(serverDevices);
```